# Getting a 500 error when making HTTP post request in Angular/ Node.js

Tags: node.js, angular, http, http-status-code-500

I was stuck when trying to make a post request with Angular httpclient, here is the code I used to export data in Angular service:

```
/* UPLOAD_URL = "https:/semi.edu/uploadData" */

    this.http.post(UPLOAD_URL, this.tracker.traverse_order).subscribe(
      (response) => console.log(response),
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );
```

And this is the code I included in app.js (node.js file):

```
  var db = require('./db');
  var express = require('express');
  var app = express();

  app.post('/uploadData', bodyParser.json(), (req, res) => {

    let insert_sql_statements = [...];

    db.connection.query({
      sql: 'INSERT INTO `collected_data` (articles) VALUES ?',
      values: [insert_sql_statements]
    });
```

And here is the error message:

[image: Internal server error 500]

And the server error log:

[image: server log]

Comment: You must have an error in your server console that should give more insights of what is happening.

Comment: Can you post the console log of node js server?

Comment: Updated the error log on server

Comment: Well, there you go, `tracked_data it not defined` on app.js, line 106 :)

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out!. In app.js I wrote "tracked_data = req.body" and that was undefined, so was that a problem of express.js?

Comment: Try `const tracked_data = req.body`?